# Why is the region key in Instance OCID is in different format for all regions? [Oracle Cloud Infrastructure]

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

For Frankfurt region, Instance OCID looks like below.

ocid1.instance.oc1.**eu-frankfurt-1**.abtheljt2tihcyimx3skqhargaklttvljkiueoiqtzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

For Ashburn region, Instance OCID looks like below.

ocid1.instance.oc1.**iad**.abuwcljtrfquxhtfl3zbwiuwuwuvhtugzxlpcpuadxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[image]

Also, what is the format for other region instances ? Which is used in the instance OCID (Region Name or Region Key) ?

Any inputs?

Comment: Why is this question down voted? Any changes I have to do, let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a design-decision that can only be explained by oracle engineers, not a specific programming problem. P.S.: we are not Oracle cloud-support....

Comment: Okay @piet. I could not have posted here.

Comment: @piet.t Instance OCIDs are used all over though API calls ([Example](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/BootVolume/ListBootVolumes), so I recommend keeping this question

Comment: @AndreTeixeira But what practical programming problem does the "why" of some non-existent naming convention solve?

Comment: @piet.t ok - you are right - this is just a naming conversion, it is by design and won't change the logic for programming.

Comment: @karthik_varma_k sorry to be 4 years late to this question, but in case you are still curious, this was just a design decision that changed within Oracle Cloud. For the first few regions that we launched, we just used airport codes. But later we realized it would become confusing for users and defeat the point of having a "legible" resource identifier format. However, we didn't want to create inconsistency among existing OCIDs, so IAD (and I think PHX) still use the short region key in the OCIDs.

Answer (score 2):

Most types of Oracle Cloud Infrastructure resources have an Oracle-assigned unique ID called an Oracle Cloud Identifier (OCID). It's included as part of the resource's information in both the Console and API.

OCIDs use this syntax:

ocid1...[REGION][.FUTURE USE].

- **ocid1**: The literal string indicating the version of the OCID.
- **resource type**: The type of resource (for example, instance, volume, vcn, subnet, user, group, and so on).
- **realm**: The realm the resource is in. A realm is a set of regions that share entities. The only possible value is oc1.
- **region**: The region the resource is in (for example, phx, iad, eu-frankfurt-1). With the introduction of the Frankfurt region, the
  format switched from a three-character code to a longer string. This 
  part is present in the OCID only for regional resources or those
  specific to a single availability domain. If the region is not
  applicable to the resource, this part might be blank (see the example
  tenancy ID below).
- **future use**: Reserved for future use. Currently blank.
- **unique ID**: The unique portion of the ID. The format may vary depending on the type of resource or service.

Example OCIDs

Tenancy:

ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaba3pv6wkcr4jqae5f44n2b2m2yt2j6rx32uzr4h25vqstifsfdsq

Instance:

ocid1.instance.oc1.phx.abuw4ljrlsfiqw6vzzxb43vyypt4pkodawglp3wqxjqofakrwvou52gb6s5a